# Calculate average timespan

Tags: c#, datetime

I am to calculate average of a set of time spans, where each time span is a subtraction between two dates.

```
DateTime a = GetStartDateTime();
DateTime b = GetEndDateTime();

var delta = b.Subtract(a).TotalDays;
```

Date format is like `22.08.2016 21:00:00`

Is there any way to do this more rationally?

Also, I am curious why my `delta` is always like `0.26914351851851853`, in other words why it is not integer?

*UPDATE:*
Here is example time spans:

```
23.08.2016 10:31:38 - 22.08.2016 21:00:00
24.08.2016 14:32:26 - 24.08.2016 21:00:00
17.08.2016 8:36:51 - 01.01.2016 21:00:00
17.08.2016 8:34:27 - 15.03.2016 21:00:00
```

Comment: `TotalDays` returns the fractional parts of the days.

Comment: Because you use TotalDays, if you want only full dates, cast it to int using `(int) b.Subtract(a).TotalDays;`

Comment: You haven't given an example of a set of time spans... it's hard to marry up your first paragraph with the rest...

Comment: Perform a simple mean calculation across the Ticks value of all your TimeSpans and create a new TimeSpan from the result. That will represent the average or mean TimeSpan.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer, @Kevin. It's the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a simple mean calculation across the Ticks value of all your TimeSpans and create a new TimeSpan from the result. That will represent the average or mean TimeSpan. e.g.

```
        var timeSpanList = new List<TimeSpan>();
        var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        timeSpanList.Add(
            new TimeSpan(
                DateTime.ParseExact("23.08.2016 10:31:38", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks - 
                DateTime.ParseExact("22.08.2016 21:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks));
        timeSpanList.Add(
            new TimeSpan(
                DateTime.ParseExact("24.08.2016 14:32:26", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks - 
                DateTime.ParseExact("24.08.2016 21:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks));
        timeSpanList.Add(
            new TimeSpan(
                DateTime.ParseExact("17.08.2016 8:36:51", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks - 
                DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2016 21:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks));
        timeSpanList.Add(
            new TimeSpan(
                DateTime.ParseExact("17.08.2016 8:34:27", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks - 
                DateTime.ParseExact("15.03.2016 21:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", provider).Ticks));
        var totalTicks = 0L;
        foreach(var ts in timeSpanList)
        {
            totalTicks += ts.Ticks;
        }
        var avgTicks = totalTicks / timeSpanList.Count;
        var avgTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(avgTicks);
```

Comment: After looking at this for a bit, I noticed that the second TimeSpan in your list produces a negative value (earlier date - later date). By subtracting here it reduces the total Ticks, thereby skewing the average (unless this is intended). If this is not the intent, you should ensure you are always subtracting the earlier date from the later date.

Comment: I know that, exactly for that reason I need to count timespan: if the timespan is negative, I surely can ignore this date.